# How to finish current activity from AccessibilityService?

Tags: android, accessibility

I am currently developing an automaticui library in which I am using `AccessibilityService`.
Currenlty I am using `performGlobalAction (GLOBAL_ACTION_BACK);` to exit from 3rd party app.
I want to know how to exit from 3rd party app when using `AccessibilityService` directly.

Answer (score 0):

If the activity lets itself finish with the back button, try this:

```
performGlobalAction(GLOBAL_ACTION_BACK);
```